# Datepicker - disabled foreground color Windows Phone 8.1 RT

Tags: datepicker, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, foreground

How to set the foreground of DatePicker for disabled state?

I have try set style res:

`<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DatePickerForegroundThemeBrush" Color="#444444" />`

and:

`dpDate.IsEnabled = false;
 dpDate.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);`

but it still transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify template of the DatePicker control in order to change it's behavior when it is in disabled visual state; actually, there is a button inside the DatePicker and you need to change behavior of that button.

1. In designer, right click on the DatePicker and then select Edit Template -> Edit a copy -> OK. Now designer has generated an style for the control.
2. Perform step one again to generate a style for the button inside the date picker.
3. Go to XAML view. There are two style elements under the Page.Resources element: ButtonStyle1 and DatePickerStyle1. Find and comment the following part:

XAML:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                       Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                    Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush"
                                       Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                    Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledBorderThemeBrush}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"
                                       Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                    Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

For a more explained example on customizing control templates, checkout [Quickstart: Control templates (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465374.aspx).